# When I edit my comment to add @user, it is not visible after apply edit?

Tags: support

I noticed 2 or 3 times that when I post comment and after that try to edit it and set @user (to reply to comment or answer) in front of the text after applying changes @user is missing.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "user" is the owner of the post then they will get notified of your comment.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but text "@user, yes you are correct ..." looks like ",yes you are correct ...". Which looks strange if I am third person who reads comments.

Comment: @new2ios - in that case just use their name without the "@"

Comment: :) ok, I just want to comment and notify them. I will take that into account next time when I will write comment with notification. 10x, @ChrisF.